# Centroids of Two Triangles Coincide.

Tags: geometry

Take a 6-gon $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6$. Let $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, $B_4$, $B_5$, $B_6$ be the middle
of the side $A_1A_2$, $A_2A_3$, $A_3A_4$, $A_4A_5$, $A_6A_1$ correspondingly. Let $O_1$ be the point
of intersection of the medians of the triangle $B_1B_3B_5$ and let $O_2$ be the point of
intersection of the medians of the triangle $B_2B_4B_6$. Prove that $O_1 = O_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple proof using vectors.

Choose a point $P$ to represent the origin. Consider each of your points as vectors from point $P$. You need two facts from vector geometry.

> 1) The midpoint of the segment $\overline{PQ}$ is the average of
>   vectors $\vec P$ and $\vec Q$.
>
> 2) The centroid of triangle $\triangle PQR$ is the average of the three vectors
>   $\vec P$, $\vec Q$, and $\vec R$.

Then $\vec B_1$ is the average of $\vec A_1$ and $\vec A_2$, etc. $\vec O_1$, since it is a median, is the average of $\vec B_1$, $\vec B_3$ and $\vec B_5$, which is easily seen to be the average of $\vec A_1$ and $\vec A_2$ (from $\vec B_1$) and $\vec A_3$ and $\vec A_4$ (from $\vec B_3$) and $\vec A_5$ and $\vec A_6$ (from $\vec B_5$).
In the same way we can easily see that $\vec O_2$ is the average of $\vec A_2$ and $\vec A_3$, and $\vec A_4$ and $\vec A_5$, and $\vec A_6$ and $\vec A_1$.

Thus, $\vec O_1$ and $\vec O_2$ are the averages of the same six points, just taken in a different order. That makes them equal as vectors, thus equal as points.

Comment: How would I use vectors to find the intersection of two lines, given that they connect midpoints of opposite sides in a quadrilateral?

Comment: How is each line defined? By two points on the line?

Comment: yeah.  So if we have quadrilateral ABCD, then we connect midpoints of opposite sides and find the point of intersection.

Comment: You have a problem that the intersection of the two lines is not itself a midpoint. It is true that the line through the midpoints of opposite sides goes through the intersection point, but that only gives you a third line through that point. The difficulty is finding the point! I don't see how averages will get your there. There are several other ways, however. I need to rush to finish grading a Calculus exam. I'll try to continue this tomorrow.

Comment: okay.  Thanks for all your help so far!